# Antivirus / Wireless PCI v2 Controls Scope

Tags: pci-dss, antivirus, wireless, pci-scope

Do the Antivirus / Wireless controls within PCI v2 apply for the entire organisation, or just for the PCI scope?

Answer (score 1):

No... but it depends if you're confident with the layer isolating what's in-scope and what's out-of-scope. If so, you're good.

PCI requirements only applies to what's in-scope - nothing else. The tricky part is actually to define this line. It has to be black and white and that's not easy - too many shades of grey.

To be sure, as always validate with a QSA (Qualified Security Assessor).

Answer (score 1):

It would be just for the scope but for the wireless you need to prove they do not cross connect.  Here I run a complete separate network and internet connection for all of our PCI stuff.